# Слайдер/карусель с поддержкой mousewheel и mousedrag

Tags: jquery, карусель, touch, mousewheel

Столкнулся с необходимостью реализовать на одном сайте контент-слайдер с поддержкой mousedrag/touch и прокруткой по колесу мыши. Наткнулся на очень подходящий мне вариант - http://hellowiktor.com/.

Пошарив по коду, понял, что он работает на Angular JS, которого, я к сожалению, вообще не знаю.

Может быть, кто подскажет подобный плагин на jQuery (в нем я хоть что-то могу разобрать и доправить/дописать)?

P.S.: Owl Carousel не предлагать :)

Comment: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Насколько я смог разобраться, slick не поддерживает прокрутку по колесику мыши

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/umv0Lz7k/1/

Comment: вариант для owl carousel - http://jsfiddle.net/f0yph3aL/

Comment: Спасибо за хорошие варианты! А можно ли как-то сделать без кол-ва слайдов, отображающихся в каруселе. Имеется ввиду точно такой же вид, как и на сайте-примере в самом вопросе. Необходимо, чтобы карусель не адаптировалась под размер экрана или родителя, т.к. размеры item'ов не должны изменяться

Comment: Может swiper подойдёт? У него есть прокрутка колёсиком.